# If $\cos(x) = y$, where $y > 0$ and $π < x < 3π/2$, how would you change $x$ to cause $y$ to be the opposite sign?

Tags: inequality

$\cos(x) = y$

$y > 0$ and $x$ is an angle radian measurement with the restriction $π < x < 3π/2$.

How would you change $x$ to cause $y$ to be the opposite sign?

Comment: How can you have $\pi<x<3\pi/4$?

Comment: My mistake. It's corrected now.

Comment: First, the way you've written that interval, that is devoid of content. I think you meant $3π/4<x<π.$ If so, then again $y$ cannot be positive.

Comment: It's $3π/2$, not $3π/4$. It was a typo.

Comment: @MurtazaUjjainwala Then correct it. Especially in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following property: 
$cos({\pi}-x)=-cos(x)$

Hence replace $x$ by $({\pi}-x)$

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you mean $3π/4<x<π$ and that $y$ is negative, then if you add $π$ to the argument $x,$ you have that the cosine becomes $$\cos(x+π)=-\cos(x)=-y,$$ although this is true in general, for any argument not necessarily confined to your interval.